# Where does querystring of "ui=2&view=dim&iv=amo1tqfqsw2s&it=ic" come from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome

In my rails app (Rails 4.2.4 Ruby 2.1.2) I have suddenly started getting errors due to weird stuff in the url.

For example where the valid url would be :

```
/note/new?client_id=nnnn
```

The url that appears from time to time on the production server is:

```
/note/new?ui=2&view=dim&iv=amo1tqfqsw2s&it=ic
```

I have no idea where the spurious querystring is coming from.

Googling seems to come up with various pages concerning Gmail but are no help.

The browser appears to be chrome when the error occurs.

Comment: people can enter this in the browser url window or use curl. if this breaks your code you should fix your code.

Comment: Why on earth would somebody enter such a bizarre querystring in the browser? Its not the sort of thing you just make up for the fun of it! It is worth pointing out that multiple users from different geographical locations all somehow got that same querystring

Comment: Does look like the little cross that google added in labs - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/uOM5CLR9xMw. But why do you care?

Comment: I care because I dont know where it is coming from and whether it is preventing users from doing what they want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same issue, turned out people was copy/pasting from their Gmail emails into our system logs/comments (we have CKEditor for logs). So every time they were looking at those logs we receive these errors on our servers. 
I've checked the log and this is content of one of them

```
<img alt="" class="ajz" id=":ps" src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/images/cleardot.gif" style="background:url(&quot;?ui=2&amp;view=dim&amp;iv=amo1tqfqsw2s&amp;it=ic&quot;)
```

So as you see this image background is pointing to those

```
ui=2&view=dim
```

Comment: It is definitely something to do with gmail and I suspect that it is when people past something from gmail into the editor on my web page (summmernote editor). However I cant replicate the error and I have no idea how to prevent it happening.